Network Folder Shared From Windows 11 Isn't Accessible
I'm trying to share a folder from my PC to all devices connected to my home network. I'm using Windows 11.
This is the host setup.
Windows 11 version:

I've enabled network discovery and file and printer sharing:

I've turned off password protected sharing:

SMB Direct is installed:

Following services are running:

Function Discovery Resource Publication
Function Discovery Provider Host
Server

Using ipconfig, my private IP is:
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.87

I've a folder which is shared with Everyone:

From the same PC, I can ping to 192.168.1.87:
ping 192.168.1.87

Pinging 192.168.1.87 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.87: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.87: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.87: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.87: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.87:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

But when I open a browser (tried with Firefox & Edge), if I navigate to http://192.168.1.87, I see:

Similarly, it's not accessible from other devices connected to the same network.
What steps I've missed to enable folder sharing from Windows 11?

you don't use a web browser to access file shares. use windows explorer instead. enter a path like \\cynaide\wonderkids-movies\  or \\192.168.1.87\wonderkids-movies\ . also don't enable smbv1 unless you really really need it (its dangerous).

One last tip: Note that share security does NOT override directory security. the user in question must have BOTH rights to access the share, and rights to access the directory the share exposes.

@FrankThomas: How can I access it from a Linux machine connected to the same network? sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.87:/ <dest> timed out.

SMB and NFS are entirely different protocols. you want to use an smbclient connection, not an NFS connection. in terms of mount command you might use cifs instead of nfs. https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/linux-mount-smb-share/ . standard windows sharing does not create NFS endpoints, only SMB. additionally the path expression in your mount command is invalid.

@FrankThomas, I was able to connect to the SMB share from Windows to Linux. Can you please add it as an answer so that I can choose it as the best answer?

So looking over your config, It looks like you created your shares successfully. I do encourage you to try removing SMBv1 related components, and Services for NFS, just to make your system more secure. if your Linux connections stop working you can reinstall SMBv1 if needed, but most Linux systems can now use SMBv2 or v3.
As for your problems, they are mostly related to your client software.
the SMB protocol does not emit HTML, so you cannot use a web browser to access file shares. Instead use Windows Explorer, and enter a path in the form of a UNC path:
\\server\share
As for your Linux mount, you had been configuring it to use NFS, but the share is SMB, so an NFS client cannot access the SMB service. Instead use a mount type of "cifs" and provide the linux version of a UNC path like:
mount -t cifs //server/share /path/to/mount/to/ 
if you wish to view an SMB share in a Linux file manager you can enter the path in a form like
smb://server/share
